# Class data attribute not being accessible in class method

Tags: python

I have written a small program that will print all the files and directories inside the path specified by me. The source code is:

```
import os
import glob

class FolderStats:
    targetdir = ""

    def __init__(self, dirpath = None):
        targetdir = dirpath
        totalfiles = 0
        totalsubfolders = 0

    def FolderIterator(self):
        print self.targetdir
        listing = os.listdir(self.targetdir)
        for infile in listing:
            print "current file is: %s" % (infile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Obj = FolderStats(raw_input('Enter your path: '))
    Obj.FolderIterator()
```

The above code is not executing. I am getting an error in the method `FolderIterator`: when the print command is executed, it prints nothing. `<targetdir>` no more contains the path supplied by me. Why is it so?

Comment: You never defined `self.targetdir`!

Comment: it is `print targetdir` not `self.targetdir`

Comment: Replace `targetdir` with `self.targetdir` in `__init__`

Comment: Thanks all how have viewed this question. I have just solved it myself. <self> keyword was missing in __init__ method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `__init__` you need to use `self.targetdir` instead of `targetdir`

```
>>> class Test:
    var = 1
    def __init__(self):
        var = 2         
        print self.var  # Object variable
        print var       # Local variable
    def func(self):
        print self.var
        print var       # this will fail, because there's no local var in this scope


>>> a = Test()
1
2
>>> a.func()
1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    a.func()
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 9, in func
    print var
NameError: global name 'var' is not defined
```